# Which browsers support stale-if-error and stale-while-revalidate?

Tags: cross-browser, cache-control

[RFC 5861](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5861) proposes the [`Cache-Control`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) extensions [`stale-while-revalidate`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5861#section-3):

> When present in an HTTP response, the stale-while-revalidate Cache-
> Control extension indicates that caches MAY serve the response in
> which it appears after it becomes stale, up to the indicated number
> of seconds.

and [`stale-if-error`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5861#section-4):

> The stale-if-error Cache-Control extension indicates that when an
> error is encountered, a cached stale response MAY be used to satisfy
> the request, regardless of other freshness information.

to allow stale content to be used for longer when a response cannot be revalidated.

These are [supported by CDNs](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/cdn-rfc5861-support.html), including [Fastly](https://docs.fastly.com/guides/performance-tuning/serving-stale-content) and [KeyCDN](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/keycdn-supports-stale-while-revalidate).

`stale-while-revalidate` is also [mentioned in the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-stale-while-revalidate-response) (`stale-if-error` is not).

What is the state of support in browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of May 2019, according to the compatibility tables of [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Browser_compatibility) and [Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5050913014153216), `stale-while-revalidate` is:

- supported in the [beta releases of Firefox 68](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases/Firefox_68) ([tracking](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1536511))
- due to [be supported in Chrome 75](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5050913014153216) ([tracking](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348877))

These will be the main releases of those browsers on [2019-07-09](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/Calendar) and [2019-06-09](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule) respectively.

`stale-if-error` doesn't appear to have current, or planned, support.

(See the RFC author's blog [Chrome and Stale-While-Revalidate](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/01/chrome_and_stale-while-revalidate) for more detail on *why* to implement this in browsers.)